# If statement in multiple SQL triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need some help with MySQL triggers, and my guess is it should be quite simple. I have a db which consists of 3 tables (trable1, table2, table3), each of these has two columns (column1, column2). So here is what I need. If a row is inserted into table1, I want it to be automaticaly replicated to table2 and table3. Likewise with updates on table2 and table3. But here is a trick, I heed an if condition, which checks if the row is already there, otherwise SQL throws me an error. I would be really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to throw an error or do you want to avoid it?

In the first case, you could do something like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2or3 WHERE col1 = NEW.col1) THEN
   SIGNAL ...
END IF;
```

Read more about signals [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html).

If you don't want to throw an error there's also the possibility to

```
INSERT INTO foo(col1, col2) VALUES (NEW.col1, NEW.col2) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE whatever = whatever;
```

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed.

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Or

```
INSERT IGNORE ....
```

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html).

Comment: Although I finally found that my problem lied in php, thanks alot for the comprehensive answer!